Transaction will not broadcast: 0/ not confirmed not in mempool
Found wallet.dat file from 2013
Fee is high, blockchain is synced, and network is stable.
Bitcoin core v27
I could use some direction or alternative solutions. The goal is to send bitcoin from this wallet to an exchange. Happy to tip whoever helps. Thanks in advance

Are you sure it’s a Bitcoin Core wallet file and not for the client of another cryptocurrency? I assume that you have made at least one backup of the wallet file. What happens when you try to -rescan? If you could provide a few more details, it might be easier to figure out what the problem is.
